# Dispatching custom events in Angular 6

Tags: angular, router, web-component, custom-element, custom-events

I have a custom element that I created, where if a specific element is clicked, it dispatches a custom event. I'm new to Angular and I'm struggling to direct the user to a specific route, based on the custom event.

I already have all the routes/paths declared in my app-routing.module.ts. Below is part of my component:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

export class Example implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.router = router;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.element.addEventListener('locationsSelected', function(evt) {
            console.log('clicked');
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/locations');
        }
    }
}
```

'clicked' shows up in the console when I click my button, so it does recognize the custom event. However the error claims my router is undefined within the scope of this eventListener. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You have a simple scope binding problem - `this` is not the instance inside that `function`. Use an arrow function or explicitly `.bind(this)`. Also note that Angular provides native functionality for doing things like handling click events - I'd recommend reading through [the tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial).

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what i needed.